# h2 jpa delete method not working java

Tags: java, database, jpa, h2, entitymanager

im trying to test this method to remove an entity from the h2 database:

```
public boolean delete(T entity) {
     if (entity == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    boolean ret = true;

    EntityManager em = entityManager();

    try {
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        em.remove(em.merge(entity));
        tx.commit();
    } catch (RollbackException ex) {
        ret = false;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }

    return ret;
}
```

that method is returning true if the entity is in the database and removes it, but it also returns true if the entity given is not in database. Can someone explain me why? thx.

Comment: Would removing an non-existing entity cause an exception?

Comment: thats what im trying to do, but don't know if it works really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`merge` will persist an entity if it doesn't already exist.  Thus, you are creating an entity (with `merge`) and then deleting it right away (with `remove`).  Thus no exception is thrown.

If you want to remove an entity and return a boolean whether you removed it or not then you could do...

```
public boolean delete(T entity) {

    if (entity == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    EntityManager em = entityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();

    try {
        tx.begin();
        em.refresh(entity);
        em.remove(entity);
        tx.commit();
        return true;
    } catch (EntityNotFoundException ex) {
        tx.rollback();
        return false;
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        tx.rollback();
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: so how i should do it?
becouse i deleted the merge but its still the same

Comment: refresh method throws EntityNotFoundException or you can check if entity exits in db by find method. Find will return null if entity doesn't exist.